# How to properly show CAGradientLayer On programmatically written view?

Tags: swift

Trying to set gradient color to a button on a programmatically written View Controller. but it won't appear!

I've tried adding the sublayer with designated index or adding the gradient sublayer in viewdidload closure and still nothing!

```
private let getStartButton : UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("GET STARTED", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(getStarted), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        button.isHidden = false
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.lightGreyBlue.cgColor, UIColor.sea.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
        gradientLayer.frame = button.bounds

        button.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)


        return button

    }()


    fileprivate func setupBottomControls() {

        view.addSubview(getStartButton)
        getStartButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
        getStartButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        getStartButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width-32
        ).isActive = true
        getStartButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

    }
```

It is Showing just the title of the button.

Comment: Where's `CAGradientLayer` in your code?

Comment: Sorry.  I was testing it in viewdidload that's why I forgot to mention it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying

```
gradientLayer.frame = button.bounds
```

But the button has no bounds. So the layer has no frame.

The button will not have any size until the autolayout constraints kick in, after `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: I've Added the gradient layer clarification in the viewed load and added the sublayer directly to the     getStartButton . still nothing

Comment: Yes that’s what I said. `viewDidLoad` is too soon.